# What is the synchonization lifecycle of globalStorageUri on CodeSpaces

Tags: visual-studio-code, codespaces

Our extension needs to store data that should be shared for all VSCode instances of a user.  We were previously storing those data in the home directory of the user. On CodeSpaces, my understanding of the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/advanced-topics/remote-extensions#persisting-extension-data-or-state) is that we should use the `vscode.ExtensionContext.globalStorageUri` location to store the data. BTW the documentation refers to `globalStoragePath` but it seems to be deprecated in favor of `globalStorageUri`.

What is not clear to me is how the synchronization between multiple CodeSpaces works.
I did a quick test:

- create a new CodeSpace in repoA
- install my extension
- check that file is created in `/home/codespace/.vscode-remote/data/User/globalStorage/myExtensionId/myFileToPersist`
- open a new CodeSpace in repoB (same GitHub user)
- `/home/codespace/.vscode-remote/data/User/globalStorage/` is empty (I was  expecting the folder `myExtensionId` to be synchronized with the other CodeSpace of repoA)
- install my extension (I though maybe the sync happens lazily only when the extension is installed)
- file `/home/codespace/.vscode-remote/data/User/globalStorage/myExtensionId/myFileToPersist` is created from scratch (different content than in repoA)

So to me it seems the `globalStorage` mechanism is not working for CodeSpaces, or maybe I don't use the API correctly. Or maybe I have wrong expectations... Can someone clarify how it is supposed to work? When is the synchronization happening? How are conflicts solved?